# How to append data to an existing database, without affecting the data already present?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I builded an application and released a version of it and made it live for the users, so the database of the live server has some live data now. Parallely I was working to add new features to the application, now as I am ready with the new changes I have some important data on my local database which I want to push to the live database server without hampering the data which was already present there on the live server.
Could anyone suggest the suitable method or a process to follow and achieve this task.
I am developing the application using Python 2.7.3 and Django 1.4 and the database which I am using is MySQL 5.5.

There is no change in the database table structure as such just the data is to be inserted without affecting the existing data. But there is a lot of relations between tables.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That completely depends on the nature of the data and the way they are organized.

In the easiest case, you just add the additional, new data; if some fields and tables have changed, it maybe gets more complicated.

If you get more precise, you'll be able to get more precise answers.

---

For example, you can do

```
d1 = mysql.connect(database1)
d2 = mysql.connect(database2)

with d2 as c2: # new transaction
    c2.execute("SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM table")
    with d1 as c1:
        c1.executemany("INSERT INTO table (f1, f2, f3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", c2)
```

if you can connect both DBs from 1 host.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I updated my question. There is no change in the database table structure, just new data which is there in the local database is to be pushed to the live database.

Comment: @Prateek Then I don't see the problem. Just add the new data to the old tables. You'll get different primary keys, but everything else you just can copy. How to do so depends on the way you connect to the databases.

Comment: Can you please be more explicit as I am handling this issue for the first time, do I have to use the mysql commands like insert or update or if I take the datadump. sorry for troubling you buddy.

Comment: @Prateek Did you see my edit?

Comment: Yes buddy I am trying to run it, just a small query that I have to run these commands from the command prompt or from the mysql command prompt, as I am doing the development on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: I got the way to run it sorry for troubling you as soon as I will solve the issue I will surely correct the answer which you posted. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Do you know how I can I leave the records which are already present in the live database but are also in the new database to be pushed.

Comment: @Prateek I don't understand. You leave things by not deleting them... or do you mean "omit them"? Try `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: I want to have the records which were already present in live database and insert the new ones (but the database table which I want to push already has some of the data which is there on the live database). How do we handle foreign key constraints following this method.